# Specific input value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I am creating a website. I want that when a specific text is entered, in and `<input>`, and then submited with `<button>`, javascript alerts the page and reply with a specific thing. Ex: if the entered input is `$ip`, the `alert()` function of js will send your ip, or like if you do `$add 2 2`, it will alert `2+2=4`.

**html**

```html
<form>
    <input class="text" id="txt">
    <button id="btn" class="submit-btn" onclick="get()">submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```js
function get() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    alert(inputVal);
    };
};
```

Comment: Use a switch case for the `inputVal` and based on that, parse the string and do it. And as this stays - the question is tooooo broad to answer. Like you're asking us to create a complete bot program for you.

Comment: You should first learn javascript instead of aiming for ready codes.

Comment: So learn how to break up a string and parse the values and compare what the user entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the input value when form has submitted and do whatever you want with the value. like this:

```js
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const value = document.getElementById('txt').value.trim();
  switch (value) {
    case '':
      break;
    case '$ip':
      alert('You IP:xxx');
      break;
    case '$add 2 2':
      alert('2+2=4');
      break;
    default:
      alert(value + ': is not a valid action');
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
  <input class="text" id="txt">
  <button id="btn" class="submit-btn">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That add method is incomplete! `:P` It's just not in our scope to answer this thing.

Comment: It's just an example of how to get entered value and make decision related to the value.

Comment: I know, I was just pulling you... But yea, we need to tell what's the scope of answers here.

Comment: Yea, that's right. thanks.